# Issue with creating and then updating existing elements in Realm database

Tags: swift, database, realm

I have a realm database which consists of Year -> Month -> Day -> Items

arrows go from parent category to the child category.
I am able to save the calculation once but if I do it again it will throw an error that Month of a primary key 0 already exists. I do know what it exists that is why I want Realm to update it. As I want to save each month only once and each year only once.

```
//MARK: - Realm Database Saving option
@objc func saveCalculation(){
    let date = Date()
    let dateElements = getDate()

    let yearObject = Year()
    yearObject.number = dateElements.year

    let monthObject = Month()
    monthObject.number = dateElements.month
    monthObject.monthName = dateElements.monthName

    let dayObject = Day()
    dayObject.id = realm.objects(Day.self).count
    dayObject.date = date
    dayObject.number = dateElements.day
    dayObject.dayName = dateElements.dayNameInWeek
    dayObject.hoursPerDay = hoursPerDay
    dayObject.ratePerHour = ratePerHour
    dayObject.minutesOfNormalPay = minutesOfNormalPay
    dayObject.earnedPerDay = earnedPerDay
    dayObject.howManyRows = rowViews.count

    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(yearObject, update: true)
            yearObject.months.append(monthObject)
            realm.add(monthObject, update: true)
            monthObject.days.append(dayObject)
            realm.add(dayObject, update: false)

            for (index, row) in rowViews.enumerated() {
                let item = Item()
                item.id = index
                item.date = date
                item.amount = Double(row.amountTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
                item.price = Double(row.priceTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
                print("Item amount: \(item.amount) and price: \(item.price)")
                dayObject.items.append(item)
                realm.add(item)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



}

func getDate() -> (day: Int, dayNameInWeek: String, month: Int, monthName: String, year: Int) {
    let date = Date()
    let dayNameInWeek = date.getDayName()
    let monthName = date.getMonthName()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)

    let year =  components.year!
    let month = components.month!
    let day = components.day!

    print(year)
    print(month)
    print(monthName)
    print(day)
    print(dayNameInWeek)
    return (day,dayNameInWeek, month, monthName, year)
}
```

each database class respectively:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Year: Object {
    //@objc dynamic var year = Date()
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var number: Int = 2008
    let months = List<Month>() //forward relationship to Months

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Month:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Month: Object {
@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var number: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var monthName: String = ""
@objc dynamic var monthYear: Int = 0
let days = List<Day>() //forward relationship to Days
let parentYear = LinkingObjects(fromType: Year.self, property: "months") //back relationship to year

override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
 }
}
```

Day:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Day: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var date: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var number: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var dayName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var hoursPerDay: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var ratePerHour: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var minutesOfNormalPay: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var earnedPerDay: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var howManyRows: Int = 0
    let items = List<Item>() //forward relationship to Items
    let parentMonth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Month.self, property: "days") //back relationship to months

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Item:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var date: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var amount: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var price: Double = 0.0

    let parentDay = LinkingObjects(fromType: Day.self, property: "items") //back relationship to days
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `year month day` just a single Date property on Item?

Comment: It is as well but as I want to use sectioned tableviews I wanted to put them in their respective containers and for the sake of browsing the database in the future it will be less data to go thru

Comment: yeah i'd just use the right date queries for that

Comment: could you direct me into the right direction with this?

Comment: Perhaps I am overcomplicating it. I dont know how to section it with months and years without it

Comment: You could set up 3 fields: "month", "year", "day" on top of your date field.

Comment: I can do that it would be quite a simple change but i dont know how to query it later so that it is sorted based on year then month and days, and to add the years and months as sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem with some if else conditions. If someone knows a cleeaner way of writing it then please post it below, as I am really interested of getting this code shortened.

```
//MARK: - Realm Database Saving option
@objc func saveCalculation(){
    let date = Date()
    let dateElements = getDate()
    var isParentYear = false
    var isParentMonth = false

    let yearObject: Year
    if let currentYearObject = realm.objects(Year.self).first(where: {$0.number == dateElements.year}) {
        yearObject = currentYearObject
        isParentYear = true
    } else {
        yearObject = Year()
        yearObject.id = realm.objects(Year.self).count
        yearObject.number = dateElements.year
    }

    let monthObject: Month
    if let currentMonthObject = realm.objects(Month.self).first(where: {$0.monthYear == dateElements.year && $0.number == dateElements.month}) {
        monthObject = currentMonthObject
        isParentMonth = true
    } else {
        monthObject = Month()
        monthObject.id = realm.objects(Month.self).count
        monthObject.number = dateElements.month
        monthObject.monthYear = dateElements.year
        monthObject.monthName = dateElements.monthName
    }


    let dayObject = Day()
    dayObject.id = realm.objects(Day.self).count
    dayObject.date = date
    dayObject.number = dateElements.day
    dayObject.dayName = dateElements.dayNameInWeek
    dayObject.hoursPerDay = hoursPerDay
    dayObject.ratePerHour = ratePerHour
    dayObject.minutesOfNormalPay = minutesOfNormalPay
    dayObject.earnedPerDay = earnedPerDay
    dayObject.howManyRows = rowViews.count

    do {
        try realm.write {
            if isParentYear && isParentMonth{
                print("Parent Year is: \(isParentYear) and parent Month is: \(isParentMonth)")
                monthObject.days.append(dayObject)
                realm.add(dayObject, update: false)
            } else if isParentYear && !isParentMonth {
                print("Parent Year is: \(isParentYear) and parent Month is: \(isParentMonth)")
                yearObject.months.append(monthObject)
                realm.add(monthObject, update: true)
                monthObject.days.append(dayObject)
                realm.add(dayObject, update: false)
            } else if !isParentYear && !isParentMonth {
                print("Parent Year is: \(isParentYear) and parent Month is: \(isParentMonth)")

                realm.add(yearObject, update: true)
                yearObject.months.append(monthObject)
                realm.add(monthObject, update: true)
                monthObject.days.append(dayObject)
                realm.add(dayObject, update: false)
            } else {
                print("THISH SHOULD NEVER BE CALLED IF CALLED SOMETHING IS VERY WRONG")
            }

            for (index, row) in rowViews.enumerated() {
                let item = Item()
                item.id = index
                item.date = date
                item.amount = Double(row.amountTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
                item.price = Double(row.priceTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
                print("Item amount: \(item.amount) and price: \(item.price)")
                dayObject.items.append(item)
                realm.add(item)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }     
}
```